# Does God care for oxen?

Tags: 1-corinthians, law, intertextuality

In I Corinthians, Paul seems to argue that it is unreasonable to think that a precept of the law that ostensibly deals with the care of oxen actually is written out of care for oxen, but it is instead completely about financing his apostles:

> 1Co 9:9  For it is written in the law of Moses, Thou shalt not muzzle
>   the mouth of the ox that treadeth out the corn. Doth God take care for
>   oxen?  10  Or saith he it altogether for our sakes? For our
>   sakes, no doubt, this is written: that he that ploweth should plow in
>   hope; and that he that thresheth in hope should be partaker of his
>   hope. (KJV)

Is the answer to his rhetorical questions "No, God doesn't care about oxen, he says it entirely about funding his apostles"?

Comment: This question was referenced on [Mi Yodeya – Judaism StackExchange](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61935/1705)

Comment: 1 Corinthians 9:9-10 echoes Christ's own words from Luke 13:14-15 and 14:3-6.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the question is rhetorical, expecting the negative response, but no, this does not suggest Paul thinks that God is unconcerned about animals or that this Old Testament passage was originally about Apostles.

Paul was attempting to draw the reader's attention to an Old Testament passage which **clearly** teaches the same principle Paul was trying to teach the Corinthians, hence the rhetorical nature of his question. (Of course, such an argument would only have worked if the meaning of the OT passage was **clear** to both parties.) Paul's assumption was that the meaning of the OT passage *would be* clear enough to his readers -- unless they *completely* missed the point of it and took it to be about being nice to cattle!

The problem, of course, is that for many modern exegetes, it's ***not*** immediately apparent how the OT passage would offer clear support for Paul's argument! Paul was an expert in the Law and a very skilled exegete, so to grasp Paul's logic, it is helpful to first grasp the meaning of the OT passage through careful study of the Law in its original language and context. Hebrew professor Dr. Jan Verbruggen has done this, and has presented his findings in an article for the Evangelical Theological Society. ([Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.etsjets.org/files/JETS-PDFs/49/49-4/JETS_49-4_699-711_Verbruggen.pdf&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiOiY3C-J7HAhVROIgKHTNCDzY&usg=AFQjCNFMIVOnK3W1y0B78aOA6h2GmAWT8w&sig2=d01hAaIaSU-F02dY3hvgBw)) His conclusion, after extensive examination of the nature of the Law, parallel ANE law codes, the Hebrew, etc. is that **the statement was never about being nice to cattle -- it was about not short-changing your neighbor by weakening his animal when you rent it for working your land.** In other words, it's just like all the other stipulations of the Law; it was meant to maintain justice and prohibit people from using others for personal gain to their detriment.

So Paul wasn't saying that God doesn't care about animals (cf. Matt. 6:26) or that the OT passage was about Apostles (in which case his rhetorical question would have been completely ineffective); he was making an **appeal** to the **clear** principle from the **plain** reading of this OT passage as support for his argument. Basically, "even the Law says you shouldn't short-change your neighbor for services rendered!".

---

Anecdotally, I do wonder if Paul didn't pick this particular law in order to suggest that he was a mere laborer (like an ox) and the one they were really being dishonest with was his master (God).

Comment: While the article was imaginative and well written it clearly is not what Paul had in mind since Paul clearly concludes that it is the unbridled ox that expects compensation, not the imagined owner:   "...For our sakes, no doubt, this is written: that he that ploweth should plow in hope; and that he that thresheth in hope should be partaker of his hope." (KJV)  In what way is the imagined renter "plowing in hope" since he is not plowing at all?

Comment: @WoundedEgo It is not the renter "plowing" but the ox, and by implication, its owner. I'm not sure what you meant by "the ox expects compensation". You think Paul's trying to say that an ox is consciously working because he expects to receive fair payment for his labor? This seems to me to miss the point of both passages completely.

Comment: what does short changing mean?

Comment: I think the parallel passage in 1 Tim 5:18 makes it all crystal clear:  1Ti 5:17  Let the elders that rule well be counted worthy of double honour, especially they who labour in the word and doctrine. 
1Ti 5:18  For the scripture saith, Thou shalt not muzzle the ox that treadeth out the corn. And, The labourer is worthy of his reward. 
  It is the laborer (the ox) that is to be unmuzzled so they get their reward. So also the apostles must be unmuzzled by being permitted to gather their compensation from those they serve. Clear as day.

Comment: @SharenEayrs It's a more polite way of saying "swindle", " use", and clearer phrases I probably shouldn't repeat on this site. To state it positively, "compensate people for the services they render you." Paul was working for them, serving them in ministry, and yet they provided him no compensation. They were like a man who rents his neighbor's ox and then deprives it of food as it labors, and then returns it weak and hungry.

Comment: @WoundedEgo Except that Paul says in 1 Cor. that it *wasn't* originally about being nice to oxen, so you'd have to either say Paul wasn't very experienced at exegesis (and good luck supporting that) or you'd have to explain Paul's exegesis, and respond adequately to Jan's top-notch research.

Comment: Paul recognized that the obvious meaning was "let the laboring beast eat" but he went over the top saying that it was never about the ox but rather about the apostles. He wasn't exegeting he was polemicizing. His point was not "let the beast eat" but rather "it means to let the apostles receive offerings". We know he was overstating his hand because he makes this untenable assertion:   1Co 9:10  Or **saith he it altogether for our sakes? For our sakes, no doubt, this is written**: that he that ploweth should plow in hope; and that he that thresheth in hope should be partaker of his hope.

Comment: I mean, look at the context!   1Co 9:4  Have we not **power to eat** and to drink? 
1Co 9:5  Have we not power to lead about a sister, a wife, as well as other apostles, and as the brethren of the Lord, and Cephas? 
1Co 9:6  Or I only and Barnabas, have not we power to forbear working? 
1Co 9:7  Who goeth a warfare any time at his own charges? **who planteth a vineyard, and eateth not of the fruit thereof? or who feedeth a flock, and eateth not of the milk of the flock?** 
1Co 9:8  Say I these things as a man? or saith not the law **the same** also?

Comment: @WoundedEgo It sounds like you already had your mind made up before asking the question. Shame...

Comment: Looks like Paul wants money.

Comment: @Jas3.1  Unlike yours? I gave careful consideration to the article you posted and your defense thereof but having weighed it I found it wanting for the reasons given. Had you a better case you would have prevailed.

Comment: @Jas3.1, whereas Paul says that the laborer is worthy of his pay you seem to insist on reading it that the laborer's owner is worthy of the pay but that is not in the text and defies the logic of the text and the many examples of the text of what he means; planting and eating, feeding and drinking. The muzzle is not to be put on the ox, not the owner. There is no owner laboring in these passages.

Comment: @SharenEayrs Read on... he clearly says in the verses that follow that he does ***not*** want their money. In context, he is simply trying to provide them an example of what it looks like to lay aside your rights in order to keep your brother from stumbling.

Comment: @WoundedEgo Again, it is the ox that is laboring, and by implication, its owner. The question is not whether this concept makes sense to ***you***; the question is how the passages would have been understood by the ancients. As Dr. Verbruggen has shown, there is ample evidence that the ancients routinely understood this to be referring to rented oxen. If you want to discuss further set up a chat room, but it sounds to me like you're on a mission to scoff at Paul's exegesis and I'm growing weary of this.

Comment: @Jas3.1 I guess the means you would like the last word.